# Base64 String in JSONRequest Java

Tags: java, json, rest, base64

I'm handling a Web Service and need some help. The process is that a pdf will be encoded with base64 and sent to my web service. I will then decode it back into a pdf and place it in the appropriate folder. The issue is that the request needs to contain the actual giant base64 string. First question is is this possible. Second, I am using postman to make the requests and was wondering how to even copy the base64 string into it. It seems there's a string limit. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no limit on the size of a POST on the browser side (except for the one set by the webserver), so this should not be an issue. As for postman: not a clue

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about postman but I can suggest to use JAX-RS and implement a [ReaderInterceptor](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/ext/ReaderInterceptor.html) and a [WriterInterceptor](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/ext/WriterInterceptor.html) using [Base64.Decoder#wrap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Decoder.html#wrap-java.io.InputStream-) respectively [Base64.Encoder#wrap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html#wrap-java.io.OutputStream-).

Otherwise, maybe postman has similar features?

Use streams like these as much as possible to reduce memory usage.

Tutorial:
https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9806

Answer (score 0):

Alright it just seems to be an issue with Postman. When you place a string of that size it will give you errors and only put a certain length per line. It will still receive the entire string. I am able to receive it and decode it. Thank you all for your help!